# Android sslpeerunverifiedexception no peer certificate, JSON SSL

Tags: android, json, ssl

I read a lot of topics all over the web and mostly on stack overflow.. I still cannot get my code working the right.. I am still getting: ***Android sslpeerunverifiedexception no peer certificate***

This is my code, and if someone can help me I would be grateful:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<String> nameArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> countryArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    String graveUrl = "https://example.com/grave.json";


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new json().execute();

    }

    class json extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            HttpClient httpclient = createHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(graveUrl);

            try {

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();

                if (statusCode != 200) {
                    return null;
                }

                InputStream jsonStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(jsonStream));
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }

                String jsonData = builder.toString();
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                JSONArray name = json.getJSONArray("graves");

                for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject video = name.getJSONObject(i);

                    nameArrayList.add(video.getString("ID_line"));
                    countryArrayList.add(video.getString("ID_grave"));
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Hello" + nameArrayList.get(0).toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    public static HttpClient createHttpClient() {
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params,
                HTTP.DEFAULT_CONTENT_CHARSET);
        HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(params, true);

        SchemeRegistry schReg = new SchemeRegistry();

        schReg.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
                .getSocketFactory(), 80));

        schReg.register(new Scheme("https",
                SSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 443));

        ClientConnectionManager conMgr = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(
                params, schReg);

        return new DefaultHttpClient(conMgr, params);
    }

}
```

Mostly of the code I got it on stack overflow but looks like I cannot put the pieces together that it works correctly..

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end looks like something was wrong with my code, because with this code everything works:

```
    class UpdateTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL("https://url.com");

            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            String jsonData = convertStreamToString(in);

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonData);   

            JSONArray name = json.getJSONArray("graves");

            for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject video = name.getJSONObject(i);

                lineArrayList.add(video.getString("ID_line"));
                graveArrayList.add(video.getString("ID_grave"));
            }

        } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This server uses untrusted certificate, hence the exception. You can bypass this by creating your own SSL socket factory, or adding certificate on your device.

Comment: I don't think that the server uses untrusted certificate because is issued by RapidSSL CA.
Or it doesn't make difference by who the server is issued?

Comment: use the link in the browser. Firefox says that it is untrusted.

Comment: I don't know which link did you try in firefox because the one I wrote in my code is a "fictional" link.. The real link from where I am trying to get my json start with this: "https://api.kasper.si"
And I checked the link with a tool from this site: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

And it say that the link is trusted..so I guess it is not true that the server uses untrusted certificate..
I have stil to bypass or add the certificate to my device or is something wrong with my code..I can give you the real link to the json if someone would like to try I would appreciate it...